Getting Error: toMatchAriaSnapshot() must be called during the test in Playwright+cucumber+js
I have been facing the issue at toMatchAriaSnapshot() assertion in playwright with cucumber and javascript. Did anybody come across this issue? Please help me in resolving this issue?
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

await expect(this.taskTimeLine).toMatchAriaSnapshot(`
            - text: "/Modified on: \\\\d+:\\\\d+ PM Completed Task Task completed by:/"
            - text: Closed
            - button "Assign"
            - button "Add to Queue"
            - link "Open Record"
            - button "Delete"
            `);

Following is the error log in VS code:
Error: toMatchAriaSnapshot() must be called during the test
           at Object.toMatchAriaSnapshot (/Users/<>/PlaywrightProjects/<project>/node_modules/playwright/lib/matchers/toMatchAriaSnapshot.js:34:24)
           at Object.toMatchAriaSnapshot (/Users/<>/PlaywrightProjects/<project>/node_modules/playwright/lib/matchers/expect.js:98:30)
           at /Users/<>/PlaywrightProjects/<project>/node_modules/playwright/lib/common/expectBundleImpl.js:338:834
           at Object.o [as 8103f153e03154d440ebdeb070612411$toMatchAriaSnapshot] (/Users/<>/PlaywrightProjects/<project>/node_modules/playwright/lib/common/expectBundleImpl.js:338:849)


Please share your full test context. Are you calling this code in the test, as the error suggests? If you're not calling it in a test, try doing so--the error is self-explanatory. If you are calling it in a test, then the question becomes interesting, but we'd still need a [mcve] and probably a package.json to be able to assist.

Please share minimal reproducible example, help us in helping you.

And with proper formatting.

I am calling this code in gherkin step as using cucumber in project.
await expect(this.taskTimeLine).toMatchAriaSnapshot(            - text: "/Modified on: \\\\d+:\\\\d+ PM Completed Task Task completed by:/"             - link "TH365 DEVTEST"             - text: Closed             - button "Assign"             - button "Add to Queue"             - link "Open Record"             - button "Delete"            );
Then('Validate that Create Activity task is created and completed', async function() {
await this.workOrdersPage.assertCreateActivityTask();
});

For now using expect(page.locator).toMatchAriaSnapshot() method is possible only in scope of Playwright Test runner since the matcher checks testInfo and takes a snapshot dir path from there:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/packages/playwright/src/matchers/toMatchAriaSnapshot.ts
